# How to know which version of QML module is loaded?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt-quick

I want to check which version of a QtQuick module has been loaded.

There is an environment variable `QML_IMPORT_TRACE` you can set to display debugging info about the imports. I set it to `1` in the QtCreator project and got details in the console, mostly the path of the libs.

> QQmlImportDatabase::addImportPath:
>   "/QT_INSTALL/5.9.3/gcc_64/qml"
>   QQmlImportDatabase::addImportPath: "qrc:/qt-project.org/imports"
>   QQmlImportDatabase::addImportPath: "/home/PROJECT_FOLDER"
>   QQmlImports(qrc:/main.qml)::addLibraryImport: "QtQuick" 2.0 as ""
>   QQmlImports(qrc:/main.qml)::importExtension: loaded
>   "/QT_INSTALL/5.9.3/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick.2/qmldir"
>   QQmlImportDatabase::registerPluginTypes: "QtQuick" from
>   "/QT_INSTALL/5.9.3/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick.2"
>   ...

Based on the path of the installation you probably can guess the version of QtQuick from the Qt version...
But is there any direct way to display the exact module version at runtime?
(and ideally without debugging the imports)